# In Extjs how to select multiple records by using ctrl key and by selecting the checkbox with mouse in extjs grid

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6-classic

how to select multiple records by using ctrl key and by selecting the checkbox with mouse in extjs grid. i am using the checkbox model for displaying the checkbox in the grid, please let me know how to achieve the multiple selection only by selecting checkboxes when we press ctrl or shift key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved by adding keyup,keydown listeners. Please find the fiddle where i updated the code.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2d98

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to use [`selModel`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.grid.Panel.html#cfg-selModel) config for [`grid`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.grid.Panel.html) using [`CheckboxModel`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel.html).

- A **selModel** Ext.selection.Model instance or config object, or the selection model class's alias string.In latter case its type property determines to which type of selection model this config is applied.
- A **CheckboxModel** selection model that renders a column of checkboxes that can be toggled to select or deselect rows. The default mode for this selection model is MULTI.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2d1r)**, I have create a demo using two grid. In first grid you can select record by `ctrl/shift` key and In second grid you can select directly on row click. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve you requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        //define user store
        Ext.define('User', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            alias: 'store.users',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: [{
                name: 'Lisa',
                email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-111-1224'
            }, {
                name: 'Bart',
                email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1234'
            }, {
                name: 'Homer',
                email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1244'
            }, {
                name: 'Marge',
                email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1254'
            }, {
                name: 'AMargeia',
                email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1254'
            }]
        });
        //Define custom grid
        Ext.define('MyGrid', {
            extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
            alias: 'widget.mygrid',
            store: {
                type: 'users'
            },
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }]
        });

        //create panel with 2 grid
        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                //select multiple records by using ctrl key and by selecting the checkbox with mouse in extjs grid
                xtype: 'mygrid',
                title: 'multi selection example by using ctrl/shif key',
                /*
                 * selModel
                 * A Ext.selection.Model instance or config object,
                 * or the selection model class's alias string.
                 */
                selModel: {
                    /* selType
                     *  A selection model that renders a column of checkboxes
                     *  that can be toggled to select or deselect rows.
                     *  The default mode for this selection model is MULTI.
                     */
                    selType: 'checkboxmodel'
                }
            }, {
                //select multi record by row click
                xtype: 'mygrid',
                margin: '20 0 0 0',
                title: 'multi selection example on rowclick',
                /*
                 * selModel
                 * A Ext.selection.Model instance or config object,
                 * or the selection model class's alias string.
                 */
                selModel: {
                    /* selType
                     *  A selection model that renders a column of checkboxes
                     *  that can be toggled to select or deselect rows.
                     *  The default mode for this selection model is MULTI.
                     */
                    selType: 'checkboxmodel',
                    /* mode
                     *  "SIMPLE" - Allows simple selection of multiple items one-by-one.
                     *  Each click in grid will either select or deselect an item.
                     */
                    mode: 'SIMPLE'
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: hi, I am need to achieve multi selection only with combination of ctrl/shift key with mouse click on checkbox, in demo i am not seeing that.

Comment: i got it, fixed my problem,i will update on the fiddle. Thank you Narendra

Comment: @user3629299 hearty welcome. If  this answer is helpful for you  so you accept this answer.